# WebView clicking on link results in about:blank

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a WebView in my application and I do a search on google. When I click a link there, let's say stackoverflow.com, it redirects me to a white page and the url is about:blank (new tab?).
I already tried this

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but it does not have any effect on this behaviour. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed it with this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719293/google-search-links-in-the-webview-of-my-app-opening-of-a-blank-page)

```
    @Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{
    System.out.println("onPageFinished: " + url);
    if ("about:blank".equals(url) && view.getTag() != null)
    {
        view.loadUrl(view.getTag().toString());
    }
    else
    {
        view.setTag(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That normally happens while accessing https URLs which have untrusted certificates. Have you tried this yet?

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tested it now and I still have the same problem :/ And I just checked it also happens with non https sites